# Extracting IP and port from multiple sockaddr_storage's into a char*

Tags: c, arrays, char, ip, port

I have a fixed length array, every entry is from type struct contact

```
typedef struct contact
{
    int fd; 
    union
    {   
        struct sockaddr_in v4addr;
        struct sockaddr_in6 v6addr;
        struct sockaddr_storage stor;
    };  

    char buf[FRAME_BUF_LEN];
    int len;    
    char name[32];
} contact_t;
```

and I need to extract the IP and port for every entry into a char*.
The result should look like this

```
192.168.0.1 1234\n192.168.0.2 1235\n192.168.0.3 1236\n //and so on..
```

I honestly have no clue how to get the information and allocate the correct size for the final char*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (for example) `struct sockaddr_storage stor`'s member `ss_family` to determine the address family and depending on this chose `v4addr` or `v6addr` to be used with [`inet_ntop()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html).

The port number comes in network bytes order, so it shall be pass to [`ntohs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htons.3.html) before being used.

The members of `v4addr` and `v6addr` to be used could be drawn from `<netinet/in.h>`:

```
/* Structure describing an Internet socket address.  */
struct sockaddr_in
{
  [...]

  in_port_t sin_port;                 /* Port number.  */
  struct in_addr sin_addr;            /* Internet address.  */

  [...]
};

/* Ditto, for IPv6.  */
struct sockaddr_in6
{
  [...]

  in_port_t sin6_port;        /* Transport layer port # */

  [...]

  struct in6_addr sin6_addr;  /* IPv6 address */

  [...]
};
```

---

To create buffers with a size unknown at compile time, use dynamic memory allocation in general.

For successivly allocating a memory block of increasing size, like when looping through your arrray and adding *address:port* tuples use [`realloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) in particular.

Comment: I will look into the usage of inet_ntop(), thank you! I assume once the usage is clear I can just iterate over the array, then for every element I use inet_ntop() to extract IP and port and append it to an exisiting char* which I realloc on every step (to the current size + the new ip+port).. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Yes, roughly that's it. @apoc (please see the update to my answer on port numbers)

Comment: sorry for using three comments to tell you now I got it.. thanks a lot man